# How can I demonstrate that, in a degenerate system, if $[H_0,\lambda H_1] = 0$ then $ H_1$ is already diagonalized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, commutator, perturbation-theory, matrix-elements

In the context of degenerate perturbation theory, for a perturbed Hamiltonian $H_0 + \lambda H_1$, I've heard of a very useful tool:

> "If $[H_0,\lambda H_1] = 0$ holds (both parts of the hamiltonian commute) then $H_1$'s matrix must be diagonal, this is, the $(\lambda H_1)_{ij} = <n_0^i| H_1 |n_0^j>$ (where $|n_0^i>$ are the unperturbed eigenstates of $H_0$) must be zero outside of the diagonal."

This would allow us to apply non-degenerate perturbation theory to the problem. I'm writting a text about degenerate perturbation theory and I'm not sure how to explicitly demonstrate this tool.

Comment: "I'm writting a text about degenerat perturbation theory..." Oh really? Who is the publisher and do they have a proofreader?

Comment: @htf Mea culpa. I dropped the OP's participle endings myself without finishing the job. What if the proofreader is in Portuguese? In any case, the "I've heard quote" merits more scrutiny... I wish I knew where *it* came from...

Answer (score 3):

Your quote is an exaggeration: $H_1$ may be diagonalized, which then fixes the ambiguous parts of the basis of the degenerate $H_0$. "Already" is out of place in an ambiguous basis.

If $[H_0,H_1]=0$, then $H_0,~H_1, ~ H=H_0+\lambda H_1$  can be simultaneously diagonal matrices. The zeroth order basis is ambiguous in the degenerate subspace, but you have already diagonalized the hamiltonian, if you have diagonalized $H_1$ which breaks the degeneracy, $\langle n_0^i | H_1|n_0^j \rangle \propto \delta_{ij}$.

You have thus found the full Hamiltonian's  *full* eigenstates, to all orders in λ, hence merely the first: the first order shifted energy is an exact expression,
$$
E^j= E^j_0 + \lambda \langle n_0^j | H_1|n_0^j \rangle.
$$

- No perturbative approximation is needed, as you have already diagonalized the full hamiltonian.

The point is $H_1$, assuming it is not degenerate itself,  helps you specify the orthogonal eigenstates ***it*** dictates by breaking the degeneracy, i.e. rotates the arbitrary zeroth order eigenstates to eigenstates of it as well.

[Illustrate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407579/eigenkets-of-degenerate-perturbation-theory) by $H_0=$diag(1,1,2), and $$
H_1=\begin{bmatrix} 3/2 &-1/2&0\\
-1/2&3/2&0\\
0&0&3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
subsequently diagonalized to $H_1=$diag(1,2,3), *without affecting* $H_0$. It is $H_1$ that fixes the above basis dubbed $|n_0^j\rangle$, *not* $H_0$.

(Freak lark logical possibility: You need *both* pieces to break each others's degeneracy in a common diagonal outcome, e.g., for  $H_0=$diag(1,1,2), $H_1=$diag(1,2,2). One should never get one's students there... They should spend their time on useful things...)